# Collapse rows with equal values in particular columns in one

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with deals data written in it. I need to query said deals while joining on other tables, however `d.originalorderid` is not a unique entry and I get several duplicate entries. I want to:

1. For each unique `d.originalorderid` select one row
2. This row should be most recent (largest ID)

How would I go about this? This is the query I have right now.

```
SELECT  d.id, 
        d.date, 
        d.ip, d.panmask, 
        d.merchantorderid, 
        d.amount, 
        d.cardholder, 
        d.bankhumanname,
        d.cardtypeid, 
        d.bankcountrycode, 
        d.usercountrycode,
        mc.paymentkey as merchantname, 
        dt.status, 
        d.merchantcontract,
        dt.tag, 
        d.originalorderid, 
        ds.refnumber, 
        ds.dealauthcode, 
        mc.processingid, 
        pc.Name as processing, 
        d.customparams       
FROM Deal as d 
LEFT JOIN MerchantContract as mc ON mc.Id = d.MerchantContract 
LEFT JOIN DealTrace as dt ON d.Id = dt.DealId 
   AND dt.id = (SELECT MAX(id) 
                FROM DealTrace WITH (nolock) 
                WHERE DealId = d.id) 
LEFT JOIN DealSummary ds ON d.Id = ds.DealId 
   AND ds.id = (SELECT MAX(id) 
                FROM DealSummary WITH (nolock) 
                WHERE DealId = d.id) 
LEFT JOIN Processing pc on mc.ProcessingId = pc.id 
WHERE (d.MerchantContract IN ('12')) 
ORDER BY ID desc OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1000 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: You'll get different answers between SQL Server and MySQL.

Comment: The generic way is to throw in another join right after `Deal`: `inner join (select originalorderid, max(id) as maxorderid from Deal group by originalorderid) md on md.originalorderid = d.originalorderid and md.maxid = d.id`

Comment: You question is confusing. You are mentioning only 1 table `deals` but in your query you are using lots of table.

Comment: Why did you throw a NOLOCK hint into those subqueries? You should remove those unless you are ok with almost always getting the MAX(id).

Comment: I would also recommend you not continue using id as the primary key column name in every table. You should give it a real name so you don't have to change the column name when it is a foreign key. DealID, MerchantContractID etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the requirement, instead of joining to the Deal table, join to a correlated subquery on it which returns the deal with the highest deal id which has the same original order id.  Test it but I think its OK..

```
SELECT ....
FROM
(SELECT *
FROM Deal d1
WHERE d1.Id=(SELECT MAX(Id)
                         FROM Deal d2
                         WHERE d2.OriginalOrderId=d1.OriginalOrderId)) d
LEFT JOIN MerchantContract as mc ON mc.Id = d.MerchantContract 
 etc etc
```